# Swagger - Set the "response" based on "consumes"

Tags: swagger

Is it possible to specify the "response" based on the "consumes" option on Swagger?

My API can return "json" or "text" and I'd like that the "example value", when the response's status is `200` changes if the user selects from `Response Content Type` the option `application/json` or `text/plain`.

This is a piece of my `swagger.json` file:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "produces": [
        "application/json",
        "text/plain"
    ],
    "consumes" : [
        "application\/json"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/writer/1/": {
            "get": {
                "summary": "Get all writers",
                "description": "Writer description.",
                "tags": [
                    "writer"
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description" : "successful operation",
                        "schema" : {
                            "$ref" : "#\/definitions\/writerResponse"
                        }
                    },
                }
         }
    }
    "definitions": {
        "writerResponse": {
            "properties": {
                "meta": {
                    "type" :"object",
                    "schema" : {
                      "$ref" : "#\/definitions\/metaDefinition"
                    }
                },
                "data": {
                    "type" :"array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref" : "#\/definitions\/writer"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "writer": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "description": "writer id.",
                    "example": "1477"
                },
                "short": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "short description.",
                    "example": "short example"
                },
                "modified": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "modified description.",
                    "example": "2016-05-21 22:58:36"
                }
            }                          
        },
    }
```

This is an example of the `JSON` output when user selects `application/json`:

```
{
    "meta": {
    "total": "1234",
    "last_page": "967",
    "per_page": "4000",
    "current_page": "1",
    "next_page_url": "http://localhost/api/<ws>/1?page=2",
    "prev_page_url": "http://localhost/api/<ws>/1?page=1",
    "from": "1",
    "to": "4000"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "short": "TEST1",
      "modified": "2011-03-07 14:17:23"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "short": "TEST2",
      "modified": "2015-05-26 12:39:45"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the output when the user selects `text/plain`:

```
id|short|modified
1|TEST1|2011-03-07 14:17:23
5|TEST2|2015-05-26 12:39:45
```

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: No, no solution... :-(