# Request based response in open api

Tags: swagger, api-design, openapi

Hi i am learning Open API Specification and i am having a doubt regarding the request and response 
[As Described in this link](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/3.0.0-rc0/versions/3.0.md#operationObject)
 There is a requestBody object and a Responses object for a path. But i have to define that for a particular input there should be particular output with respective error code How can implement this in Open API Specification

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger; specify two responses with same code based on optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576447/swagger-specify-two-responses-with-same-code-based-on-optional-parameter)

Comment: Also related: [How to specify alternative response formats with swagger/OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39136565/113116), [Swagger - Set the “response” based on “consumes”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38827278/113116), [How to define different responses for same HTTP status code in OpenAPI (Swagger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47447403/113116), [How to specify multiple 404 causes in OpenAPI (Swagger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40640669/113116)